# Read from a file that changes everyday in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to automate a program that reads a file, processes it and then write it to a new file. The problem is that a new file comes in every day, and the contents are similar, the input file and output file names will change daily. The file name will be in the following format: SAPHR_Joiners_20110323. As you can see the first part of the name will be constant but the date will be unique...... How would i be able to do this?

Thanks alot guys

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do.  You'll need to ask in more details.

Comment: what stops you to use: "APHR_Joiners_"+DateTime.Now.ToString(format); or something like.

Comment: @Daniel this is my current path variable:                         string path = @"C:/SAPHR_Joiners_20110323"; The path variable needs to be changed everyday to match the date

Comment: @Trishen: See solutions below

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which part of this are you having trouble with?  You get a much better response on this site if you've tried something and have a specific problem, rather than just asking people to write an application for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just generate the filename dynamically in your program, and then open the corresponding file? So something like this:

```
string filename = "SAPHR_Joiners_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string[] filecontents = File.ReadAllLines( filename );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the latest file in a folder, you could query the created date, using [System.IO.File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx)

In code:

```
string myFile = 
            Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp")
            .OrderBy<String, DateTime>(file => File.GetCreationTime(file))
            .First();
```

However, if you know that the file-name will follow a strict naming convention, then it is better to access the file by generating the file name as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to look for new incoming files if you want prompt respone, otherwise just locate the file based on a current date. If you have further problems, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Back the days of VB6 one technique that still is in use this days is the `folder monitoring`

You keep checking if a folder has files, every x in x minutes, or in your case, every day at XX hours for example.

and you could create a Service from your program and that will insure that it will run every time (as long as the machine is on) :)

Those days, in VB6, we didn't had so much as you have today, so, for watching a folder for specific file types (or anything at all) `*.*` you can use the [`System.IO.FIleSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) (example in that page), and to process the file, just use [`System.IO.TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) for example